# Angular custom library doesn't work with Electron

Tags: angular, electron, angular-library

I'm trying to use a custom Angular component library which I´ve made in an Electron project. I have already use this library in an Angular project and it does work correctly, so I'm assuming the problem is something related with the library and Electron.

After installing all dependencies and setting all up, I can start the app, but it starts completly white as if nothing is loading. Only one error at console:

[image: Console error]

After some research, I couldn't find any workaround as the error isn't descriptive.

If there is any file or setting that can help for the answer, ask for it in a comment and I'll edit the post to add it!

[edit 1]

After some tries I ran the angular project by itself and it didn't work either. Same error.
Also, by removing the `CustomLibraryModule` from my `app.module.ts` fix the error. But i need to use the library as a mandatory requirement.

Comment: maybe there are problems with the angular version. I would first try to use the same angular version for the project with which the components library was created

Comment: @Josh publish the answer! The points are yours! Thanks

Comment: If this is useful for someone, what happened: My library was created with the last version of angular (11.2.x). Then, my electron project was created months ago with a previous version of angular (11.0.x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe there are problems with the angular version. I would first try to use the same angular version for the project with which the components library was created